# Problem with update-manager: No module named 'apt_pkg' in Ubuntu 13.10, having installed Python 3.4 on /usr/local/lib

Tags: 13.10, apt, update-manager, python3

I'm rather new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to run update-manager on Ubuntu 13.10. I get:

```
jacopo@jacopo-laptop:~$ update-manager 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module> from ._gi import _API
ImportError: No module named 'gi._gi'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
from gi.repository import Gtk
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from ._gi import _API
ImportError: No module named 'gi._gi'
```

As far as I have understood, this is a problem related to the fact that I should have python3.4 installed. I installed it in `/usr/local/lib`, but I always get the same error. In this way I can't even upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 69):

Reinstall `apt_pkg` using:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

The error is primarily because of library `apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` not being present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

Removing and reinstalling should help.

Comment: It's almost always preferable to reinstall the package in one step using `sudo apt install --reinstall <package-name>`, because this avoids calculating and removing dependencies (and marking packages for removal). Be aware that removing packages is *not* always a reversible procedure; for example APT will remove itself or its dependencies if asked to! The `--reinstall` flag is therefore much safer than `remove` followed by `install`. The `remove` command by itself does not remove configuration files of a package so has no benefit over `install --reinstall`.

Comment: This answer should be updated with the suggestion by @Zanna, removing python3-apt will remove a ton of dependencies and may scare the crap out of someone, not to mention messing up their system.

Comment: So uninstall apt-package with `sudo dpkg -r --force-depends apt-package` instead which uninstalls only apt-package but not any of its dependencies.

Comment: i had to use `sudo apt remove --purge python3-apt` then `sudo apt install python3-apt`, the weird thing is that after reinstalling, 78 really unrelated(well I don't really know) packages were marked as no longer needed and can be `autoremove`.. I'm kind of concerned but at least it fixed my problem haha

Comment: @Kenivia I tried that command and aborted immmediately - it was about to remove half of my desktop. I guess that's why you also had so many no longer needed packages.

Comment: I have `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` but am getting that error - the reinstall changes nothing.

Comment: @Xerus in my case I have the error and the package in the right place: `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.* /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 48):

```
update-alternatives  --set python3  /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Comment: Updating alternatives for python might sometimes break things.

Comment: I used `update-alternatives  --set python3  /usr/bin/python3.5` and it worked. python3 was already pointing to `python3.6` on my system.

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. I had just followed a guide on how to update Python 3 in Ubuntu 18.04 and my apt-get no longer worked. No idea that would happen.

Comment: It worked, just use sudo.

Comment: I want to use Python 3.9 as my default though

Comment: `update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.8` solved my problem on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 35):

The following solution worked for me:

```
cd  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

If you get an error message saying too many levels of symbolic links as shown below:

```
cp: failed to access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Then you need to simply unlink the apt_pkg.so file. Use the following command:

```
sudo unlink apt_pkg.so
```

And then use the command

```
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Instead of doing a `cp`, I used `ln -s` instead. So `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` worked for me

Answer (score 28):

for me the following steps worked:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

the original solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg/36232975#36232975

Comment: As mentioned in a comment over at the "original solution," for me this worked: `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.  The `35` (python 3.5) version is what's installed regardless of the particular sub-version of python 3.x that you're running.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this worked for me when I upgraded to either Python 3.6 or 3.7, but now I have Python 3.8 and the expected file name seems to have changed to just `apt_pkg.so`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1154616/725987

Answer (score 26):

For me this did the trick:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt
```

This problem actually is similar to this one:
[apt-get broken: No module named debian.deb822](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246970/apt-get-broken-no-module-named-debian-deb822)

Comment: it removed half my system software on zorin OS, and installing doesn't get them back

Comment: This solve the issue, I've replaced the default python/pip 3.8 with python/pip 3.7, and end up by damaging the default pip causing this error on ubuntu 20.

Comment: dangerous and stupid. Do not do this. Tons of system software relies on python3-apt including apt itself. You won't be able to re-install again because the apt command will error.

Comment: Used this on Plesk and now nothing works

Comment: I changed this to reinstall rather than remove install so that it doesn't remove anything (including dependencies), it simply reinstalls the package safely.

Answer (score 8):

This solution *used* to work for me after I had upgrade to either Python 3.6 or 3.7 and add-apt-repository stopped working:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
# where 35m is the file you have and 38m corresponds to your Python version
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,38m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Now I have Python 3.8 and add-apt-repository stopped working again. I found [another, related SO question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1069087/725987), with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154616/725987) that worked for me. It appears that the expected filename is now just `apt_pkg.so`, so you have to do this:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
# where 35m is the file you have
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

The fact that the new expected filename is just `apt_pkg.so` is promising. Hopefully it means we won't have to keep doing this dance every time there's a new minor version of Python!

Comment: Worked for me thanks :)

Comment: @dave-yarwood saved my day.
"new expected filename is just apt_pkg.so"

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to upgrade 13.10 to 14.04, try following [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).  If you're just trying to update your current system from the command line, open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried but it didn't work. I tried once more now, getting, after apt-get update, the warning W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: K - you have a problem with the update sources.  I've seen several threads about how to fix that  The following link seems to be a good match for your question  http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but I still get the same error when running `update-manager`

Comment: K - that about exhausts my possibilities with out a more extensive web search.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

The problem for me was that I installed python3.7 next to python3.6 and made it the default.

I manually run the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6  /usr/bin/python3
```

so python3 now points to the correct version of python ... that solves the issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the issue because I updated to python3.7 in Ubuntu 18. But when I do what you did (create symbolic link), I got `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists`. If I do `ls` in my `/usr/bin/python*`, I have `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.6m`, `python3.7`, `python3.7m` and  `python3m`. If I do `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`, I have `*0 /usr/bin/python3.7 2 auto mode`, `1 /usr/bin/python3.6 1 manual mode` and `2 /usr/bin/python3.7 2 manual mode`. Thank you.

Comment: may be you need to delete a link file already exist or rename it to .old and create your own link.

Comment: @user1330974 did you finally solve the problem ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @user1330974 apparently, just forcing the symbolic link worked:
`ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6  /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @dallonsi Thank you. I didn't look into it further, but I'll be using your approach. :)

Comment: you should prefer `update-alternatives`, which will do this in a safer way

Comment: when `update-alternatives` fails with `error: no alternatives for python3` this the way to go. Worked for me with `python3.5` since I was upgrading Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this by copying `apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so` to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` from another desktop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have tried almost all possibilities found over internet like, purging python installation and then reinstalling, cleaning broken upgrade files etc, but ended up with no success.

Answer (score 2):

For me below was worth full

```
    mansoor@LDEVOPS-MANSOOR:~/Documents/clients/HR/DevopsSimulator$  cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

    mansoor@LDEVOPS-MANSOOR:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages$ sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: If I copied the file instead of creating a symlink, do you think that would interfere with update-alternatives, or maybe cause some other headaches for me down the road?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading to python 3.9, and recreating the symlink '/usr/bin/python3' to point to the new location.

The only solution that worked for me, was that from a comment on the first answer, from @Kenivia: `sudo apt remove --purge python3-apt`
then `sudo apt install python3-apt`

This solved the error but uninstalled my ubuntu Software Center. But it was not a big deal, because I just reinstalled it with `sudo apt install ubuntu-software` and now everything seems to be working just fine

EDIT: some issue still persisted after this (update-manger kept giving errors and wouldn't start). So I had to go back and revert the symlink /usr/bin/python3 to point to the original python3.6 location. This solved everything

Answer (score 2):

Running Ubuntu 22.10 with Python 3.10.7 my apt package manager stopped working as well with apt reporting that the `apt_pkg` was not installed. What worked for me was the following:

```
 cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
 ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
 apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt -y
 init 6
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: This on fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Just an advise: I avoid installing "my" python on /usr/local, but I have one dedicated directory per python version (e.g. in /opt) and I'm using virtual environments on my user account to use the python I need, which is activated by my .profile

By this approach, you will always avoid to change the python system expected configuration and dependencies.

Well, I know, it's too late for your case, but...

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I ended up with multiple versions of python 3.9, I had 3.9 and 3.9.12 in `ls /usr/bin/pyth*` when I checked my version I was on 3.9.12 but `sudo update-alternatives --list` only showed version 3.9. What I did was

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9.12 2

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
```

That got my `sudo apt upgrade` working, then I was able to just copy the .so file to apt_pkg.so

```
#You might need this if the package isn't there
#sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall

cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Ubuntu, the default python was `Python3.6`, which I updated my default python into 3.9, from there I started facing the same issue.

`python3 --version` Will give you a good insight about which version is current default.

After going through the threads here, What I did was examined  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

```sh
cd  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages;
ls
```

found the file:

> apt_pkg.`cpython-36m`-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

from where I understood, the issue was because, I have only dist-packages against cpython-36m but current default is 3.9 which do not have a dist package, For A quick remedy, instead of installing dist-package for 3.9, I roll back `update-alternative` to `python3.6`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps another, I finally solved this problem, that was apparently caused by python version conflicts, by redirecting the link python3, then redirecting it to the right python version:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4
```

You may need to enter the correct python version, found with

```
python3 -V
```

Comment: So you removed one version for `3.4` ?

Comment: Tried this, and found it to make things _worse_. Cannot recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem after upgrade ubuntu 19 to ubuntu 20. In ubuntu 20 default python version is 3.8 But some packages doesn't support this version. For this I downgraded default python version to 3.7 After downgrade I faced this shit problem.

This is downgrade documentation: https://blog.nixarsoft.com/2020/06/04/ubuntu-20-and-old-python-versions/

Let me tell you how to solve this problem.

```
python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import apt_pkg
>>> apt_pkg
<module 'apt_pkg' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
>>> exit
```

As you can see there is a ".so" file for apt_pkg and it is located to "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" Now if you link this file to "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-37-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" then you can use this library in python 3.7. Please take care that I changed "38" to "37" in linked file. You must be root for make link.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-37-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Probably you can do same method for other python versions. If you change 38 to 36 then you can use this library in python 3.6...

Answer (score 0):

I tried using @kodmanyagha 's answer, but no apt_pkg was found in the python environment.
I solved it thanks to @saranjeet 's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154616/390024):

```
 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages$ sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, solved it by modify the shebang of /usr/bin/add-apt-repository from:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
```