# Successful installation of module using pip3, but module not found when try to import in python

Tags: command-line, python, pip

I am a bit new to using the command line, so I apologize if this question is rather basic. I believe a have installed a module called lmfit using

```
pip3 install lmfit
```

and it says this was successful. However, I still get a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit'
```

when I try to import lmfit in a python script. I've tried to check if it was really installed using

```
pip3 show lmfit
```

and this gives the location of the module in a folder called python3.8 on my local computer.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check which version of python you are you running before you are importing the module?
`import sys`
`sys.version`

Comment: Also, please check the output of `sys.path` 
`sys.executable`
It could be possible that python is executed in some environment and the module is installed in a different environment.

Comment: @Zenquiorra Thanks! I get 'command import not found' for the first command, and also 'command not found' for all of sys,version, sys.path, and sys.executable. Unless you mean I should run these in python, not the command line?

Comment: @Zenquiorra Oh wait, I see I should run them in python. `sys.version` gives `3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]`
`sys.path` gives a bunch of path names, and I don't know what I should be looking for. 
`sys.executable` gives a file called `pythonw.exe` in my folder `Anaconda3`.

Comment: Ok found the error. A possible fix will depend on your next response!
The error is:
You are running python 3.7 and the module is installed for python 3.8.

Can you please paste the output of `python --version` and `python3 --version`.
Also, how are you running python on your system? Are you using `python` command or `python3` from the CLI? If you are using `python`, then can you please try running `python3` and importing the module there?

Comment: @Zenquiorra The output of `python --version` is 
`~$ python version                                                                                                                        Command 'python' not found, did you mean:                                                                                                                         command 'python3' from deb python3                                              command 'python' from deb python-is-python3`
The output of `python3 --version` is
 `Python 3.8.2`

Comment: I am running Python using Spyder. However, I can also run using a Jupyter notebook in Google colab which works just fine after `pip3 install lmfit`. But I still want to make it work in Spyder for future use.

Comment: I am not running it form the command line, but simply clicking on the Spyder icon, I'm still getting used to the command line :)

Comment: If the answer worked then please accept it for others users to try the solution. If not, then share the error here in comments, I will modify my solution accordingly. It is recommended that you straight away try point 3 (regarding spyder)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the `lmfit` module installed for `python 3.8` and you are running `python 3.7` on Spyder for which the module is not installed.

> Preferrable method for you is option 3 as you said you want to fix it for Spyder. The blockquote explains the detailed procedure to do that.

1. A possible fix is to change the symbolic link and fix it to `python 3.8`. You can check how to change the path [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120474/setting-python3-to-version-3-7-on-wsl) (Follow the instructions and replace 3.6 with 3.7 and 3.7 with 3.8 for your case)
2. Use a virtual environment to juggle between multiple versions.
3. Change the version which spyder uses for python. To do this:

> Open Preferences in Spyder => `Tools - Preferences`
>
> Click on `Python Interpreter` from the options in left
>
> Now the Selected option, right below `Select the Interpreter for all Python Consoles` should be `Default (i.e. use the same as Sypder's)`,
> Now change it to `Use the following interpreter:` and it will ask for
> a path below it.
>
> Provide the path to your Python 3.8 installation folder.
> You can find the path using:
>
> `whereis python3.8` in your ubuntu command line interface (Note for windows `where python3.8` should work fine).
>
> In general the path should be something like `\usr\bin\python3.8` but it depends on
> how you have installed it. Take the path to `python3.8` and paste it
> in that path. You can also browse for `python3.8` in that path and
> select it manually from the spyder interface.
>
> Now `Apply` it and `Ok` it.  Restart `Spyder` and you should be
> running python3.8 and now you can import `lmfit`  in there.

A visual representation of this process (except on how to find the path) could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882065/8229265)

Comment: Thanks @Zenquiorra. When I try to get the path using `whereis python3.8`, it outputs a bunch of file paths. This includes the one you suggest, `/usr/bin/python3.8`, but when I enter that path I get an error from the Python interpreter: 'Invalid file path:`.

Comment: Can you please try going towards this path  `cd ~` and then navigating towards `usr` and then the remaining path. You can most probably find it in `home` after going to `~`. So it should be `cd ~` then `cd home` -> `cd usr` and ... But it can vary. Try locating `usr` by `whereis usr` from the path `~`. And then paste this path to python3.8 by adding the prefix path to it from `~`
On the other hand, you also  said : _this gives the location of the module in a folder called python3.8 on my local computers_  Can you please use this path to locate python3.8 and input it in the prompt?

Comment: It is suggested if typing in/ pasting the path does not work, then you can browse for python 3.8 in the related path from the prompt and manually select it. 
Also, you open the file explorer(nautilus) and search for python3.8 in `/usr/bin` (most probably in `home`), after you have found pytho3.8, you can right click in the file explorer and there should be an option to `Open in Terminal`. Click on that and you can find the whole path to that folder in terminal. You can copy that and add `python3.8` to it.

Comment: Given that you have found python3.8 through file explorer,  If the option to `Open in Terminal` does not show up after you right click, then you can simply add it by 2-3 commands using this.: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu)

The idea here is you have to provide a global path to python3.8 in Spyder. So we are trying to find a global path, relative to `~`