# A problem has occured when checking for updates - 16.04

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, bug-reporting

There's red circle with white minus sign in the middle that says that a problem has occured when checking for updates. I'm also unable to open "Software & Updates" and "Software Center".
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software-center, but it gives me this error when I try to open the software-center via terminal.

```
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 140
    print time.time()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Appears to python2 code. Is it using python3 to interpret?

when i tried `software-properties-gtk`

it gave me this

```
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 32, in <module>
    import aptsources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with my python as I just updated python3 to python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Hey This quetion seems to have been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i) but try running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

The error is primarily because of library apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so not being present in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

Removing and reinstalling should help.

If that doesn't work, I would recommend taking a dive into your system logs.

thank you @https://askubuntu.com/users/857799/vikas-kapdoskar in advance

Comment: still getting the error for some reason after installing.

Comment: i see it in that /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Comment: Try running sudo apt auto-clean sudo apt auto-remove and then sudo apt update

Comment: ```apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so```  
I have two versions. is that normal?  
There's a symbolic link to the 34m version

Comment: try ------------- cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Comment: and typically no, when you see double when it comes to APT, it's never really good

Comment: well it i fixed it by ```sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu```
but I have another error for dbus for another post lol

Comment: Damn it michael this is why we can't have nice things! lol link me the post I will see if I can help on that one