# Terminator does not work

Tags: 18.04, python, gnome-terminal, python3, terminator

I installed `terminator` and it was working very well, but suddenly It stopped working.

When I add terminator repository, I got this error:

**Command:**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa`

**Error:**

> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

and When I ran `terminator` command in the terminal, I got this error:

```
File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
   except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use `python3.7` and `Ubuntu18.04`

**References:**

- [linuste](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/960124-err65-httpppalaunchpadnetgnome-terminatorppaubuntu-bionic-release-404-not-found/)
- [terminator](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
- [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)
- [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i)

---

#### Update

**Software and Update:**

Here is my software and update the latest status:

[image]

**Python path:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Z97-D3H:~$ which python3;
/usr/bin/python3
ubuntu@ubuntu-Z97-D3H:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
ubuntu@ubuntu-Z97-D3H:~$  ls -al $(which python python3)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec  9 08:46 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
ubuntu@ubuntu-Z97-D3H:~$  dpkg -l | grep python | grep apt
ii  python-apt-common                          1.6.4                                           all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python3-apt                                1.6.4                                           amd64        Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python3-aptdaemon                          1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1                        all          Python 3 module for the server and client of aptdaemon
ii  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets              1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1                        all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
ubuntu@ubuntu-Z97-D3H:~$
```

Comment: That PPA doesn't support any releases later than xenial (16.04), thus the *no release file* error message.  Terminator exists in Ubuntu repositories, so why was it added? PPA's are 3rd party sources for software, with security and validation on you.

Comment: Thanks your response. So I remove that dependencies and I reinstall terminator. how can I get rid of python error messages?

Comment: Did you uninstall Pythonv2?

Comment: In my case, I fixed the problem with uninstalling ``python3`` and ``python2`` and manage whole stuff with venv

Comment: yes, use new maintained repo: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use PPA to get Terminator installed. You have to remove the problematic PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
```

and then install the Terminator from *universe* pocket.

All you need is to enable this pocket and install package from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

And then use it as was planned:

> ```
> $ terminator -v
> terminator 1.91
> ```

Comment: thanks for your response, but that does not work for me. I ran the first command and I got this error: ``The team named '~gnome-terminator' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ppa'``

Comment: It seems to be expected, as you really did not add this PPA to the system, so it can't be removed. Then you can proceed with next part of my answer.

Comment: I tried other parts of your answer, but nothing changed. It threw ``No module named 'apt_pkg'``

Comment: Then try to reinstall these python modules with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt` and then retry

Comment: Even I tried that, but not thing changed

Comment: Please add output of `which python3; which python; which python2; ls -al $(which python python3 python2)` and `dpkg -l | grep python | grep apt` to the question body.

Comment: I updated the question due to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi, did it really solve your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Kira No, I just uninstall ``python3`` and then try to install ``terminator``

Comment: This can work, but if you want to keep `python3` in your system, consider my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the instructions provided on this page after the project moved to GitHub:

https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md#source-install

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is due to the fact that `/usr/bin/terminator` is invoking `python`, rather than explicitly invoking `python2`, and in your environment `python` points to `python3`.

An easy fix is to make terminator call `python2`, as it should:

```
sudo sed '1s.!/usr/bin/python.!/usr/bin/python2.' /usr/bin/terminator
```