# Installing Terminator for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, gnome, ppa, terminator

I've been trying to install terminator for my ubuntu 18.04, but I couldn't install it with apt and after adding ppa:gnome-terminator, in `apt update` I get this error:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

There is no bionic release in [ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

How can I install Terminator?

Comment: The PPA you added stopped being supported after xenial (16.04) so why was it added?   PPA's are 3rd party personal package archives meaning security (checking they support your release, the maintainers can be trusted & are reliable etc) is all on you.  That PPA should not have been added (no release file because bionic (18.04) is not supported!).

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=terminator shows `terminator` is available in default repos (if 'universe' is enabled), no PPA required)

Comment: @N0rbert that helped, but didn't solve my problem. I've found the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195264/695264), but I still couldn't install the terminator. I was checking my "Software and Updates" and I saw that in "Ubuntu Software" tab, the "Canonical-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" is not selected. I select it and after `sudo apt update`, I could install terminator using `sudo apt install terminator`.
[Ubuntu Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVNZC.png)

Comment: as i have answered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247914/terminator-permission-denied-for-sudo/#1319065, this new & maintained repo worked for me on 20.04.2 LTS: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator