# Problem add-apt-repository

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I made a mistake when try to add a repository. My intention was to install ffmulticonverter from this page : [ffmulticonverter](https://launchpad.net/~cteehayder/+archive/ubuntu/ffmulticonverter)

But insted of just `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cteehayder/ffmulticonverter
sudo apt-get update`

I made `sudo gdebi http://ppa.launchpad.net/cteehayder/ffmulticonverter/ubuntu bionic main`

Now `sudo apt update` is broken as `sudo add-apt-repository` and also in graphical mode.
    When i try to `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cteehayder/ffmulticonverter` it tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

 Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I don't know how to resolve it and bring back the update command of my distro. 
Thanks for help.

My apt source list at /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe

 # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 # newer versions of the distribution.
 deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
 # deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

#Tor
deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic main
deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic main


#PeerGuardian

# deb http://moblock-deb.sourceforge.net/debianstretch main
# deb-src http://moblock-deb.sourceforge.net/debian strech main
```

Comment: Can you please also add the contents of your source list? It is located at /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Also, this might help: [Problem with update-manager: No module named 'apt_pkg' in Ubuntu 13.10, having installed Python 3.4 on /usr/local/lib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i)