# Cannot open terminal by clicking Terminal Icon Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt, package-management, python3

I am having two issues:

1. Problem with the `apt_pkg` installation
2. I cannot open terminal by clicking on the icon anymore.

At first, I had a problem with `apt_pkg` :

```
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

So I searched and found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i). It suggests that this is caused by installing python3.7 on the default python3: python3.6 ,and then changing alternative or something (Which I did).

Then I tried Olimjon Ibragimov's answer:

> for me the following steps worked:
>
> `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`
> `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{34m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

But `apt_pkg` problem is still there. Plus, now I can't open terminal by clicking the icon or using `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T` anymore. (But I can manage to open it by right-click on some directory)

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem. I am new to linux so I really hope you can answer in details.

**EDIT**
2. Solved with [this](https://github.com/aben20807/blog-post/issues/80) (Need to fix `_gi` as well plus my stupid mistake by blindly copy and paste the command without checking for the python version in the post)

Comment: So has everything been solved or is something still outstanding?

Comment: Yes, the first issues has gone as well so I think everything is okay now.