# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I currently using ubuntu 22.04, when I do 'sudo apt update', always appear error like this :

```
$ sudo apt update 
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit:3 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Hit:4 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:6 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 3, in 
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with update-manager: No module named 'apt\_pkg' in Ubuntu 13.10, having installed Python 3.4 on /usr/local/lib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i)

Comment: Related [How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218562/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg)

Comment: Related: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' installing deadsnakes repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949591/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-installing-deadsnakes-repository)