# ImportError: No module named debian.deb822

Tags: apt, debian

My Ubuntu 14.04 setup seems to be hopelessly fouled up, to the extent that I can no longer successfully install any packages using apt-get install.  The common error is "no module named debian.deb822".  An example is below. Note that my goal is not necessarily to install this particular package; just to be able to install *any* packages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
box:~/python> sudo apt-get install update-notifier
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apturl is already the newest version.
apturl-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 394 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.154.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 26, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
ImportError: No module named debian.deb822
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 0.154.1ubuntu1); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ubuntu-releasNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        e-upgrader-gtk; however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 ubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT 1:
After running "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade," the output is slightly different but the same error is thrown:

```
box:~> sudo apt-get upgrade update-notifier
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
update-notifier is already the newest version.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-en-us
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-galaxy
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  linux-generic linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-signed-image-generic-lts-vivid linux-tools-virtual-lts-wily
  openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless python3-uno shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.154.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 26, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
ImportError: No module named debian.deb822
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 0.154.1ubuntu1); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ubuntu-releasNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        e-upgrader-gtk; however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT 2: After running @Raphael 's suggested fixes the output has changed somewhat, but the problem persists:

```
box:~/Downloads> sudo apt-get install update-notifier
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-notifier is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libreoffice-gtk3 linux-headers-3.13.0-77 linux-headers-3.13.0-77-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic
  linux-lts-wily-tools-4.2.0-27 linux-tools-4.2.0-27-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.154.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 26, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
ImportError: No module named debian.deb822
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 0.154.1ubuntu1); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ubuntu-releasNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        e-upgrader-gtk; however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 ubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: hmm I wonder why 'wily' is coming up. Maybe a problem with your `sources.list`?

Comment: @Kreuzfeld run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to fix those 5 not fully installed packages, then `sudo apt-get install <package name>` to fix those 32 heldback.

Comment: @tlhlngan: Unfortunately that didn't help; I get the same "debian" error.

Comment: @Kreuzfeld Please don't add "SOLVED" to your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the Python "deb822" and "apt"-related packages were installed, but not in the right location. I (1) identified the location of these using `locate deb822`, (2) identified where they "ought" to live by:

```
python
import numpy
print numpy
```

and then (3) copied the files into the appropriate directory via:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt* /appropriate_directory/python2.7/site-packages/
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deb* /appropriate_directory/python2.7/site-packages/
```

After that, `sudo apt-get install X` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From [Ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274564):

It is due to the unavailibility of the package `python-six`.

To install it, do:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-six
```

---

**EDIT 1**:-

Since, `apt-get install` doesn't seem to work, you can manually install it using:

```
cd ~/Downloads; wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/six/python-six_1.10.0-3_all.deb; sudo dpkg -i python-six_1.10.0-3_all.deb
```

---

**EDIT 2**:-

From [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/python-debian):

> Control files of single or multiple RFC822-style paragraphs, e.g.
>      debian/control, .changes, .dsc, Packages, Sources, Release, etc.
>      (debian.deb822 module)

So, you might need that package. To install:

```
cd ~/Downloads; wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-debian/python-debian_0.1.28_all.deb; sudo dpkg -i python-six_1.10.0-3_all.deb
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run this apt-get install command I get the same basic error message: "ImportError: No module named debian.deb822"

Comment: @Kreuzfeld - Does the update command run successfully?

Comment: @Kreuzfeld - Edited the answer with another alternative.

Comment: Thanks, but after installing python-six manually, the same problem still occurs: 32 packages "held back," 5 "not fully installed or removed," and failing via "no module named debian.deb822."

Comment: @Kreuzfeld - Edited the answer with another alternative solution

Comment: Not much of a change; the same "debian822" error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have 394 packages that have not been updated. Most likely this is causing dependency issues.
Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks -- I ran this, but the main problem still seems to persist. I've updated the Original Post.